# bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=False) works manually (by using mouse and keyboard) but not using bpy

Tags: python, snapping

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 201, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor.poll() failed, context is incorrect
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

I am typing in this command, because I already got selected object before snapping:

```
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=False)
```

The question is: why I can not snap selected object to 3d cursor using bpy python while being able to do it by using mouse and keyboard?

Comment: The question is why I can not snap selected object to 3d cursor using bpy python while being able to do it by using mouse and keyboard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - 3DView Border Select](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/python-3dview-border-select)

Comment: I am afraid border select is something different.

Comment: no, it is the same: just replace border select by your bpy.ops.view3d command with override as first argument

Comment: If that helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM4Ct.png

Comment: Or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Comment: It works, thank you everyone, now I just have to reverse engineer it :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185175/python-code-to-add-objects-to-the-3d-cursor   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164734/how-to-move-selected-object-to-the-curser-location-using-a-python-command/164779#164779

Answer (score 2):

as @lemon says the answer is override the context

import bpy

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        override['region'] = area.regions[4]
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor( override, use_offset=False)
```